# Remove default images embedded in WordPress default deployment

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress 4.9.6 through a siteground deployment.
It's my first WordPress deployment.

I've conducted a "Chrome Lighthouse audit". To my surprise the following images were found embeded in my website. Side note: the objective of the website is indeed to test and break things.

```
<img src="https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/cb4cf0c066e80c220ca7b12536f6ab12?s=256&amp;d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D256&amp;r=G">

<img src="https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/3c783597e0beddd06c039cdde994a54b?s=256&amp;d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D256&amp;r=G">

<img src="https://1.gravatar.com/avatar/7f21d8bc48e0c073cb9c4bd1892d79c6?s=256&amp;d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D256&amp;r=G">
```

[image]

I can't seem to figure out:
- Where they come from
- They're not displayed but they're referred to.
- How to delete them.

Could you advise on the above?

As an FYI - Most important / heavy plug-ins I'm running.
- Jetpack by WordPress.com
- Yoast SEO

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch off the gravatar settings under settings->Discussion